# Missing inbox notification for new answer to my question

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

Someone posted [an answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/14315/4483) to [one of my questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/13935/why-do-i-have-a-different-version-of-stopping-by-woods-on-a-snowy-evening) on May 16th. Here is the timestamp of the answer:

[image: Screenshot of answer timestamp]

Yet as you can see in the below screenshot of my inbox notifications, the only notification that I received on May 16th was for a bounty that was expiring:

[image: Screenshot of inbox notifications]

Is there any reason why this answer shouldn't have generated a notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [timeline](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/14315/timeline) shows that the answer was deleted shortly after being posted by the post author. Deleted posts don't show in your inbox because it would be confusing.

The post was edited and undeleted today which is why you see the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was deleted less than an hour after it was posted, and we also remove the notification for it so users don't end up on a page wondering why they were notified of nothing. It was only undeleted less than an hour ago.